# communicating with a scale using USB vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have been given a project at work to write VB.net code that will communicate with a shipping scale using USB. Unfortunately I have never written anything to communicate with USB before so I have no idea how to go about this. I have searched the net and found plenty of ways to do it with C#. But everything I find with VB.net I cannot get to work. I came across this code which looked promising unfortunately I'm getting the error "System.Managermant.ManagementObject is not defined". I imported System.management  and I still have the error. I need an example of how to communicate with a USB device

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim strDeviceName As String
        Dim strQuotes As String
        Dim arrDeviceNames As Array
        Dim USBDevice As System.Management.ManagementObject
        Dim objReturnCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection

        'Dim ObjScope As New System.Management.ManagementScope("\\FullNameOfYourComputer\root\cimv2")    'This is optional. Can be used for remote connections.

        Dim SearcherUSBDevicesCollection As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_USBControllerDevice")
        Dim ReturnUSBDevicesCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection
        ReturnUSBDevicesCollection = SearcherUSBDevicesCollection.Get

        'Or
        'Dim USBDevicesClass As New System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_USBControllerDevice")
        'Dim ReturnUSBDevicesCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = USBDevicesClass.GetInstances()


        For Each USBDevice In ReturnUSBDevicesCollection
            strDeviceName = USBDevice.Properties("Dependent").Value.ToString()
            strQuotes = Chr(34)
            strDeviceName = Replace(strDeviceName, strQuotes, "")
            arrDeviceNames = Split(strDeviceName, "=")
            strDeviceName = arrDeviceNames(1)

            Dim objSearcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & strDeviceName & "'")
            objReturnCollection = objSearcher.Get()

            Dim objReturn As System.Management.ManagementObject

            For Each objReturn In objReturnCollection
                Me.ListBox4.Items.Add("Description: " & objReturn("Name").ToString())
                Me.ListBox4.Items.Add("DeviceID: " & objReturn("DeviceID").ToString())

            Next
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBnet and C# are perfectly interoperable so you might ask at work if you can use C# code, that, nevertheless, compile to the same .net intermediate language. Or you can use one of the online converters to get VBnet code from C#.

Comment: Now can anyone tell me how to communicate with the scale?

Comment: I think now it's up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project settings and add a reference to System.Management.

Comment: Nope, he imported the name space but did not wrote that he added the reference. Importing a namespace isn't enough, you need to add the reference too.

Comment: btw. I tried the code and it worked fine just by adding the ref

Comment: Looks like my big problem with running this is that I was using 3.5 framework and that reference was not available. I changed it to 4 and Bingo. Thanks for the help.